# Overpass API List All Nodes along a region

Tags: overpass-api

I would like to know if it's possible to query nodes and attach additional information to it.

In my case I am trying to get all bus stop of Mauritius with a additional column specifying the district where the bus stop belongs. What means the district columns values will be repeated many times.

Maybe, should I do a loop on the bus stops instead?

This is my attempt, listing the districts, but I can't add the bus stops.

```
[out:csv(district_name, bus_stop_id)];

area["ISO3166-1"="MU"][admin_level=2];
relation(area)["admin_level"="4"];

foreach->.district(
  
  (
    node(area.district)["highway"="bus_stop"];
    way(area.district)["highway"="bus_stop"];
    rel(area.district)["highway"="bus_stop"];
  );
  make count district_name = district.set(t["name"]);
  out;
);
```